# Cannot access directory on Windows share, even though it looks like I have permission

Tags: windows, permission, monterey, sharing

MacOS 12.6, MacBook Pro

I am attempting to use a Windows share exposed through a VPN from one of my company's servers. I can connect through the VPN, mount the share, and then see in the Finder the top-level folders.

All of the folders except one show the red "No Access" icon, and sure enough trying to open one of those folders fails with a "don't have permission" popup. The one folder that *doesn't* show the red icon seems to work fine.

When I open the "Get Info" view for the inaccessible folder I need, and then open the "Sharing & Permissions" panel, it shows that I have "Read & Write" privileges. It also shows (after the entry for my user name in the network) an entry for "everyone" with "No Access". I'm not sure what that means.

I haven't tried to use a Windows share from a MacOS machine before, so I'm not sure whether the problem is on my end or on the Windows network side. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I'd recommed that you double-check with your company's IT that access permissions to that folder are properly configured, the information the Finder displays for shared folders is not always accurate. If access permissions are correct, it'd be interesting to know if that folder is set up differently, for example, if it is accessible using DFS (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/dfs-namespaces/dfs-overview and https://support.apple.com/guide/directory-utility/distributed-file-system-namespace-support-ior598b5f4f9/mac).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the original issue was, but after rebooting the Mac, restarting the VPN, and reconnecting to the share, I had access. I had been through that cycle at least twice (as I had little else to do) and it had not worked, but I tried the next morning and it was fine.

Personally I don't like answers that aren't really *solutions*, but here we are. I have some suspicions that there were larger network issues involved, as my company had undergone an office move that affected the network to some extent.

Comment: A reboot sometimes works miracle in resolving network/caching related issues, so it helpful to have this here as a reminder.